# Do deleted comments count toward badges?

Tags: support, comments, badges, deleted-comments

The question seems pretty straight forward.  This is a curiosity, rather than a concern.  It was brought on by a couple recent situations:

- On programmers, I just got the commentator badge, but it took (at least 11) comments to get, as I deleted (at least) 1 comment before hitting 10.  Is this proper behavior, or should the deleted comment(s) count toward the badge?
- On SO, I recently made a comment to a question.  The comment got several upvotes, but later the question was deleted.  Will the comment count toward that coveted   ;-)  pundit badge?

Comment: Regarding your second bullet point [see this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109627/commentator-badge-awarded-for-8-comments/109629#109629)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Deleted *anything* will not help you get a badge (save for Disciplined and Peer Pressure).