# Commentator badge awarded for 8 comments

Tags: support, comments, badges, comment-badges

Got a commentator badge today. Though my [activity tab (filtered on comments)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/166025/aziz-shaikh?tab=activity#page_1-filter_comments) shows only 8 comments. Either the [10 comments limit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/31/commentator) has changed or the SO App was generous to me today. Thanks for the badge, don't take it away :)

Comment: Probably 2 of the comments were deleted after the badge was awarded. Don't worry the badge won't be removed.

Comment: @Nick why not keep the [bug] tag and change to [status-bydesign]? Looks more proper to me.

Comment: @Shadow - because it's not a bug...

Comment: @Nick the badge description says "Left 10 comments" - so plainly speaking, for those not familiar with the way the system works, it looks like a bug. I'm not trying to be picky, just see it from newbie point of view.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In addition to those 8, you have comments on 2 posts that have been since deleted [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106910/navigationbar-not-positioned-correctly-how-to-solve-this-problem) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104118/where-can-i-ask-a-question-about-choosing-a-platform) (visible to 10k users).  The badge is behaving correctly...it's just that comments on deleted posts won't show up in your activity tab.

Enjoy your badge!