# Does a comment on deleted posts count towards badges?

Tags: support, comments, badges, deleted-posts

I've read a post on meta about [deleted comments count towards badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79550/do-deleted-comments-count-toward-badges).

But, I need to clarify the thing that whether the comments on a deleted post be counted towards badges(commentator, pundit).

I can't see those comments in my profile, but, those comments could be visible on the deleted posts.

Comment: ...how does the post you link not answer your question?

Comment: Confirmed by Nick Craver♦ http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109629/

Comment: @Bart, the answer reveals that deleted anything willnot be counted towards badges, here the post got deleted, not the comment

Comment: Ah, like that @Azik. In that case the question linked by Aziz seems to be a fitting duplicate.

Comment: @Bart, can't find that question on my small search :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does a comment on deleted posts count towards badges?

Yes, it does. Nick Craver♦ confirmed it here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109629/.

> Does a deleted comment count towards badges?

No, it does not. Confirmed by mmyers♦ here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79555/.

Comment: The mmyers answer is contradicted by Nick's answer (the questioner there specifically mentioned the case of commenting on a deleted post) so I'm not sure how credible it actually is. It may have been based on assumption.